# How to write a countdown Timer without using a plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

With jquery as you can see in this picture, but how can I create a timer countdown without using a plugin? please help

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem when trying to create a countdown?

Comment: As you can see in the picture, I can't divide the hour or  minute or second into 2 parts

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You have not clarified the issue and have not shown any effort. Please try harder

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

Comment: Thank you ,but my problem is that I can't break it down into parts shown in the picture with jquery

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days; // Change the variable here to split it ("days, hours, minutes, seconds" 

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you ,but my problem is that I can't break it down into parts shown in the picture  with jquery

Comment: yes you can use the "day, hours, minutes and seconds" variables to break it down

Comment: I have written the my code  below,  can you help me over it please?

Comment: I didn't mean it, for example, 10 seconds,  write it separately as 1 and 0, want separate it as in the picture

Comment: var day = 10;
    let outputExample = []
    let sNumber = day.toString();

    for (var i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i++) {
        outputExample.push(+sNumber.charAt(i));
    }

    console.log(outputExample);
    console.log(outputExample[0]);
    console.log(outputExample[1]);

Answer (score 0):

What can I add here so that I can divide the day or others as shown in the picture

$('[data-countdown]').each(function(){
var $deadline = new Date($(this).data('countdown')).getTime();

```
        var $dataDays = $(this).children('[data-days]');
        var $dataHours = $(this).children('[data-hours]');
        var $dataMinuts = $(this).children('[data-minuts]');
        var $dataSeconds = $(this).children('[data-seconds]');

        var x = setInterval(function(){

            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var t = $deadline - now;

            var days = Math.floor(t/(1000*60*60*24));
            var hours = Math.floor(t%(1000*60*60*24) / (1000*60*60));
            var minuts = Math.floor(t%(1000*60*60) / (1000*60));
            var seconds = Math.floor(t%(1000*60) / (1000));

            if( days < 10 ){
                days = '0'+days;
            }

            if( hours < 10 ){
                hours = '0'+hours;
            }

            if( minuts < 10 ){
                minuts = '0'+minuts;
            }

            if( seconds < 10 ){
                seconds = '0'+seconds;
            }

            $dataDays.html(days);
            $dataHours.html(hours);
            $dataMinuts.html(minuts);
            $dataSeconds.html(seconds);


            if( t <= 0 ){
                clearInterval(x);

                $dataDays.html('00');
                $dataHours.html('00');
                $dataMinuts.html('00');
                $dataSeconds.html('00');

            }



        },1000);
    })
```